# Create a crafing recipe for a SpawnEgg of Items

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am currently programming a little Minecraft Mod in Java with Forge 1.8 where i want to make a little R2D2 unit. This has gone great so far. But now I want to make a `CraftingRecipe` for my R2D2-SpawnEgg of to Items.

I tried to make a simple craftingrecipe with a `ItemStack`, but don't know how to get the SpawnEgg in there so that i get it when i put the two Items together in a Workbench.

Here is a example of how I tried to make it:

```
EntityEgg StackR2d2Head = new EntityEgg ();
GameRegistry.addShapelessRecipe(new ItemStack(r2d2body), (r2d2head));
```

Does anyone know how to make one?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have gotten the arguments for "GameRegistry.addShapelessRecipe" wrong, it takes an ItemStack that should be the output of the recipe and then and Object[] of all of the required Items. Try changing your code to this:

```
ItemStack output = new ItemStack(Material.MONSTER_EGG, 1, <ENTITYID>); 

GameRegistry.addShapelessRecipe(output,
new Object[]{
  new ItemStack(r2d2body),
  new ItemStack(r2d2head)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace "r2d2body" and "r2d2head" with "[Class that your spawn egg is in].[Name of spawn egg]"

Let's say I am making a crafting for planks of a wood I made. Well, I would put:

```
GameRegistry.addShapelessRecipe(new ItemStack(ModItems.coolwoodplanks, 4), 
<input here>)
```

That is a rough example of what I am trying to say...
Basically, I made an item and I registered it in the class "ModItems". So, you need to put [Class].[Item]

That's all. tell me if that works